# Slim template engine syntax for [if lt IE 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I use slim as view template engine http://slim-lang.com/

How would you write the following piece of code with slim?

thanks

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Looking briefly at their documentation, it seems that `/!` only allows to write a comment line but it doesn't support "conditional" comments like that. I would encourage you to write a patch for Slim that allows such comments.

Comment: I [added documentation](http://rdoc.info/gems/slim/frames) to [slim-lang](http://slim-lang.com) to cover this topic.

Answer (score 13):

It should use /!

```
/![if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]
```

Answer (score 8):

Looking through the documentation [github-slim-template/slim](https://github.com/slim-template/slim#ie-conditional-comment-) I found:

**IE conditional comment /[...]**

```
/[if IE]
  p Get a better browser.
```

renders as

```
<!--[if IE]><p>Get a better browser.</p><![endif]-->
```

In your case you could write:

```
/[if lt IE 9]
  script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"
```

Answer (score 6):

Looking at Slim's source code for Slim::Parser, it seems that you can do it this way, although I haven't tried.

```
/[if lt IE 9]
  <script src='http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this question searching for a method to do both downlevel-reveal and downlevel-hidden conditionals in Slim.

First make sure you are clear on the difference between these two types of conditionals. CSS-Tricks has a great post about [downlevel-hidden and downlevel-reveal conditionals](http://css-tricks.com/downlevel-hidden-downlevel-revealed/).

This code creates a downlevel-hidden conditional.

```
/[if lt IE 9]
  ...
```

But if you want a downlevel-reveal conditional you need to just write it as you would if you were not working in slim.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><!--> ... <!--<![endif]-->
```

I encountered this issue while trying to use HTML5 Boilerplate in Slim. [This Gist](https://gist.github.com/ryanburnette/8198991) shows my approach to the issue.

If slim has a syntax for writing downlevel-reveal conditionals I am not aware of it.