# Slim conditional external JavaScript file for IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, slim

I am trying to include https://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js for IE8 only in a slim template.

I have tried solutions suggested in [Slim template engine syntax for [if lt IE 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808935/slim-template-engine-syntax-for-if-lt-ie-9) and How to get HTML5 Boilerplate-style Conditional Comments Working in Slim - https://gist.github.com/helloluis/1183106 and still cannot get this working.

Has anyone actually found a solution that works?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following in the template?

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```